# Use of ArrayStore to filter grid locally

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I need to `FILTER` my grid based on certain criteria.

For example; if there are 3 fields, `Name,age,school`. I need to filter the grid Locally, so that it displays all students with the `age` 10 in the grid.

I read that this is achievable if i use `Ext.data.ArrayStore`. But i am not sure how to apply this in to my code. My Store class looks like this;

```
Ext.define('Project.store.Person',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'App.model.Person',   
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/person.php'
    }
});
```

My Model;

```
Ext.define ('Project.model.Person',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',   
    fields:['name','age','school']
});
```

How can i apply `Ext.data.ArrayStore`, in order to filter columns locally. Like to display all students who are `10` years of `age`.

```
**UPDATE**
```

GRID - View

```
this.columns = [
    {
{ text: "Size", dataIndex: 'size' ,filter: {
            type: 'list',
            options: ['small', 'medium', 'extra large']

        } }, ...
```

STORE

```
Ext.define('SerenExample.store.GridFilterExample',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'App.model.GridFilterExample',
    remoteFilter: false,
    remoteGroup:true,
    proxy: { ...
```

I don't see the check box saying filter, when i click on the respected column

**UPDATE**

```
Ext.define('SerenExample.view.GridFilterExample' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.gridfilt',
features: [],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = 'GridFilterExample';

        this.columns = [
    {
    ...
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
GET http://localhost/SerenExample/feature/filters.js?_dc=1341677311248 404 Not Found 104ms
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/SerenExample/feature/filters.js?_dc=1341677311248"

Ext.define('SerenExample.view.GridFilterExample' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias : 'widget.gridfilt',
features: [  {ftype: 'filters',
            autoReload: false,
            local: true,                
            filters: [{
                type: 'list',
                dataIndex: 'status',
                            options: ['small', 'medium', 'extra large']
            }]}],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = 'GridFilterExample';

        this.columns = [
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ArrayStore`. Just specify `remoteFilter: false` in your store definition and apply filter. It will be done locally.

Comment: But still i am unable to see the check box to filter the column. I have added my code in the above post. Please have a look.

Comment: That is completely different question. I thought you need to filter the store from the code. If you want to use grid filtering ability - check this sample: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html. From the first look - I think you're missing `features: []` argument in your grid definition.

Comment: Yes, i have looked at that example. I have the above code using that example. According to the example it says `features: [filters],`. I added `features: [],` to my View class, but still i don't see the check box when i click on the column. I am missing something here :S

Comment: Well, did you create that filters object? Post a code of your grid definition

Comment: Com'n... You've got to create an object of `Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature` and pass it inside filters array. Look at that sample closer. And read this http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature too

Comment: No, i had the code there, but i removed it when posting coz i thought its wrong. Anyway, i still get an error, i have added the code above.

Comment: Did you include FiltersFeature.js file somehow into your app? You have to do this manually if you're using something from ux/ folder. These components don't come standard with ExtJs code.

Comment: Yes that works. When we filter according to some property, is there any way where we could indicate the User alerting them that the results were filtered. Or else they will think that these are the only records available. is there something in-built to address this issue ?

Comment: User would use this filter, so he kind of will know that it's used. I don't think there is anything built-in other than that